# How to lower MSE using polynomial regression?

Tags: feature-engineering, mse

I have a training dataset with the positions (x and y) of three objects and their velocities at a time t. Then I have a test dataset with the initial positions and a time step x.

The goal is to predict the final positions at that time x.

1. I dont really understand why I need the velocities (if someone has an idea, I would really appreciate it)
2. I have already standardize my data (with Standard Scaler), and trained the best model with polynomial regression.
3. I have tried not standardizing it but normalizing it. However, the MSE increased a lot.

I don't know what to do more, I am just a beginner in machine learning! I want to decrease my MSE which has now a value of 0.94.

if you need more details just tell me